# Joining Tables With the Possibility of No Matching Value on the Other One

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables that I want to join.

```
      Table A
    ------------
   | owner | id |
    ------------
   |  a   |  1  |  
   |  a   |  2  |
     ..........
   |  a   |  20 |
    ------------

        Table B
    ---------------
   | a_id | number |
    ---------------
   |  1   |   2    |
   |  2   |   7    |
     .............
   |  15  |   3    |
    ---------------
```

How can I join those two tables, showing all of the records from `Table A` and ordering them by `number` from `Table B`? The total number of records in `Table A` and `Table B` is not always the same. Most of the time, `Table A` will have a few records (about 1 - 3) more than `Table B`.

I tried using a query with a `WHERE` clause that will check if `id` is equal to `a_id` or `a_id` is equal to `NULL` but it doesn't work. The result was, only `id` that exist in `Table B` (the `a_id` column) shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`LEFT JOIN`](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) if you want to return a row even if there is no matching row in the joined table:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       A
LEFT JOIN  B ON B.a_id = A.id
ORDER BY   B.number
```

The columns of the joined table will be NULL when there was no match row.